# Diffuse color in viewport displays corrupted texture

Tags: texturing

[image]When I follow the steps below, Blender shows a corrupted texture:

1. Start new file-Add Mesh-Plane
2. Scale the plane in the XY axis to a value of 10
3. In the property panel select Material properties-New
4. Deselect Use Nodes
5. Select the Base Color and reduce Alpha value

Is anyone else experiencing this behaviour?
I'm using Blender 2.92 - Windows 10 Pro 20H2

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but feel free to report a bug to the Blender devs. In the meantime, I would recommend using nodes if that fixes the problem. I can't think of a reason not to use them.

Comment: Thanks Reinis, I was just wondering if anyone else had the same problem before reporting it, or might be something wrong with my settings.

Comment: Are you using an AMD or Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200 (4 GB dedicated GDDR5).